# Why returns Int? python

Tags: python

in this video(at 7min30seconds), the code bellow I copied from this video returns 3, although
mine returns 4.04.
I do not understand why codes in the video returns Int, though mine returns Float.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWW-jA6YjHk&list=UUNc-Wa_ZNBAGzFkYbAHw9eg&index=29

```
def num_coins(cents):
    if cents < 1:
        return 0
    coins = [25, 10, 5, 1]
    num_of_coins = 0
    for coin in coins:
        num_of_coins += cents / coin
        cents = cents % coin
        if cents == 0:
            break
    return num_of_coins

print(num_coins(31))
```

Comment: In Python 3, diving ints using `/` produces a float. In Python 2, diving ints using `/` produces an int. If you want to produce an int, use `//` instead.

Comment: Adding to @khelwood's answer, you can type cast the division `int(cents / coin)`

Comment: @Abhishek why type `int( )` (5 extra symbols) when just 1 more, `/`,  suffices?

Comment: @JohnColeman It help me be specific about where type conversions are happing

Comment: @Abhishek  But `cents//coin` involves no implicit type conversion. Those are two integer variables and `//` is an integer operation. It is not an alias for `int( / )`. The only reason the YouTube code worked as it did is because in that case Python 2 was in fact using the operation which is known as `//` in Python 3, so using `//` is the way to make more explicit what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to get the right answer :

```
def num_coins(cents):
    if cents < 1:
        return 0
    coins = [25, 10, 5, 1]
    num_of_coins = 0
    for coin in coins:
        num_of_coins += int(cents / coin)
        cents = cents % coin
        if cents == 0:
            break
    return num_of_coins

print(num_coins(31))
```

`/` operator is not similar for python 2 and python 3